# (NSWindowButton) NSWindow.standardWindowButton button not highlighting

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nswindow, nsbutton

When i use the following to create a button

```
NSWindow.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.ZoomButton, forStyleMask: 0)
```

I get a button that doesn't react to mouse hover events. I can augment this by creating a container view with a `NSTrackingArea` and manually triggering the `highlight` method but it produces a clicked state.

[image]

Is there a way to somehow force the button into the expected behavior state without the darkened background?

I have been trying to avoid subclassing `NSButton`, but it seems like i may have to, and I'm just in a state of denial.

Comment: Could you provide more code? What are you trying to achieve with this button? Are you trying to use different button then default? You can subclass nswindow to get custom behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027544/resise-nswindow-without-showing-resize-button/32310904#32310904

Comment: I want no titlebar and the ability to reposition the button set. Also when a titlebar is present the window forces rounded corners.

Comment: One question only, whats the code that plays with the button. Have you seen inappstorewindow? It can save you a lot of trouble. https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow

Comment: For some reason i didn't want to use images ;X

Answer (score 1):

I could not get this working for the life of me so my solution was to write my own custom buttons. This works fine for me because my NSWindow is already custom so there wont be a clash of style.

https://gist.github.com/icodeforlove/a334884e59784b4c2567

Another viable solution is to use https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow as @xhruso00 mentioned, but it seemed like overkill.